# NULLReferenceException for DataGridView when checking for Duplicate Value

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, datagridviewcolumn

I am in the process of making a sample app where the user inputs their information which should be displayed in the datagridview. I am trying to prevent duplicate records from being inputted into the program. However, I am receving this error:
*'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'*
*System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.*
This error is in the if statement in the for loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    int value = 0;

    private void frmUsers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // The columns are already created. 
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        
        for (int item=0; item<dgvUsers.Rows.Count;item++)
        {
            if (txtFName.Text == dgvUsers.Rows[item].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Name from Previous Account");
            }
        }
        bool fname_contains = Convert.ToString(txtFName).Any(char.IsDigit);
        bool lname_contains = Convert.ToString(txtLName).Any(char.IsDigit);
        bool age_contains = Convert.ToString(txtAge).Any(x => !char.IsLetter(x));
        string[] value = { Convert.ToString(txtFName.Text), Convert.ToString(txtLName.Text), Convert.ToString(txtAge.Text) };
        if (value.Distinct().Count() != value.Count())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Provided Names Are Duplicates", "Processing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        if (fname_contains == true || lname_contains == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Name Cannot Include Any Digits!", "Processing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        if (age_contains == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Your Age Cannot Include Any Letters!", "Processing Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
        else if (fname_contains == false && lname_contains == false && age_contains == true)
        {

            dgvUsers.Rows.Add(value);
            MessageBox.Show("Process Completed", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The `Value` in that cell is `null`, and calling `.ToString()` on `null` throws that exception.

Comment: Please use Convert.ToString(dgvUsers.Rows[item].Cells[0].Value) to avoid null reference exception.  Alternative option is to add null propogation operator like this dgvUsers.Rows[item].Cells[0].Value?.ToString()